# hiding formulas in formula bar

Tags: excel, vba

When I used, in visual basic, the codes shown below, the `HYPERLINK` part appears in the formula `bar`, in the worksheet. I just want the `"TextHere"` to display in the formula bar.

What additional codes can I add? I've tried to hide it by changing its properties in the protection tab, but it does not allow me to edit the TEXT anymore. I would like it to still be edit-friendly.

```
Sub IndexingSheets()
    Sheets(1).Range("A1").Formula = _
    "=HYPERLINK(""#" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Name & "!A2"", ""TextHere"")"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**How to hide a formula from the formula bar** 

Let me demonstrate two ways of hiding formulas from the formula bar

---

## No1.

To hide the formula from the formula bar you have to set the [`HiddenFormula` property the `Range` object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838209.aspx) to `True`

It will only work while the worksheet is **protected**

So the *trick* here is:
 -> select all cells and unlock them for editing 
 -> select cells you want to hide formulas from and lock them 
 -> protect the sheet

**Select all cells and unlock them for editing**
-> select all cells, right click anywhere to format cells. Go to the `Protection` tab and unselect `Locked` 
[image: unlocking] 

**Select cells you want to hide formulas from and lock them**
-> select **A1**, right click, go to `Protection` tab and select `Locked` and `Hidden`
[image: hide formulas]

**Protect the sheet**
-> Click the `Review` tab, then `Protect Sheet` and OK ( no password necessary )
[image: protect sheet]

Now notice, you can still edit any cell except the **A1**. Look at the formula bar - ***There is no formula! Its HIDDEN!***
[image: done]

---

This is a **VBA** solution:

```
Sub HideTheFormula()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets(1)

    Call IndexingSheets

    Call Setup(ws)
    Call ProtectSheet(ws)
    'Call UnprotectSheet(ws)

End Sub

Sub IndexingSheets()
    Sheets(1).Range("A1").Formula = _
    "=HYPERLINK(""#" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Name & "!A2"", ""TextHere"")"
End Sub

Sub ProtectSheet(ByRef ws As Worksheet)
    'ws.Protect userinterfaceonly:=True
    ws.Protect
End Sub

Sub UnprotectSheet(ByRef ws As Worksheet)
    ws.Unprotect
End Sub

Sub Setup(ByRef ws As Worksheet)
    With ws.Cells
        .Locked = False
        .FormulaHidden = False
    End With
    ws.Range("A1").Locked = True
    ws.Range("A1").FormulaHidden = True
End Sub
```

---

## No2.

With a new spreadsheet insert this code in a new `VBE`(<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>) **`Module`**. Execute the **`Main`** macro from the `View Macros` window (<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>)

```
Sub Main()
    With Range("A1")
        .Formula = "=1+1"
    End With

    With Range("A2")
        .Formula = "=1+1"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```

After execution have a look at the sheets ranges `A1` and `A2`
When `A1` gets selected and you look at the formula bar you can see the formula `=1+1`, 
however when you select `A2` even though you have put a formula in the cell, it has been **`evaluated`** and **hidden** so now it displays the evaluated value *(how cool!)*
[image: evaluated]


The same principle applies when you are **pulling a value from a closed workbook**, for instance

```
Sub PullValueFromAClosedWorkbooksRange()
    With Range("A1")
        .Formula = "='C:\Users\admin\Desktop\[temp.xlsm]Sheet1'!A1"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: an exceptional answer