# Using Offset Properly

Tags: excel, offset

I have this code:

```
If Not (Application.Intersect(Target, Range("E2:F5000")) Is Nothing) Then
       If StrComp("pp voice", Target.Value, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
          Target.Value = "PP Voice"
         'disable app activation cell
       End If
End If
```

That code is fine, does what it's supposed to. What I also need it to do, is disable the cell in the same row from column M. Like disable it and fill it Grey or something.

Regards,
Ben.

Comment: What do you mean by "disable"? Lock the cell?

Comment: Yeah locking will do fine, as the sheet is protected.

Comment: Are you looking to lock a cell in column M of the `Target` row, if `StrComp() = 0`?

Comment: Yep. That IF statement just cleans up peoples crappy typing, but I also need the cell in column M locked for certain values. (The ones in the StrComp)

Comment: I was looking at something like,

`Target.Offset(Target.Row, 8).Locked = True`

But that doesn't seem to do a thing.

Comment: Try `Cells(Target.Row,13).Locked = True` If that doesn't lock the cell, then take a look at [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037400/how-to-lock-the-data-in-a-cell-in-excel-using-vba), or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17111648/how-to-lock-excel-cells-in-vba)

Comment: `Target.Offset(0, 8).Value = "this one"` - this targets the correct cell, because the value changes, but if I do `.Locked = True`, it has not effect.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, worked it out. Unlocking entire sheet, then relocking solved it.

```
   If StrComp("pp voice", Target.Value, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
     Target.Value = "PP Voice"
     ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sales Entry").Unprotect "password!"
     Target.Offset(0, 8).Locked = True
     ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sales Entry").Protect "password!"
   End If
```

Thanks for your input!

Comment: I'm going to bet it's because you have it locked, therefore can't do anything to the cell.  Instead of doing the unlocking in the `If` statement, try just adding it at the beginning of your sub, then locking it at the end. That will also probably speed it up, since it's not locking/unlocking each time.

Comment: That's exactly what I did, as there is about 25 of those IF statements lol. Cheers