# Using Find: Method 'Range' Of Object '_Worksheet' failed"

Tags: excel, vba

I want to write a macro, that in all sheets locks certain cells -- from A12 to last row of R. Thing is, that I get

> error 1004: "Method 'Range' Of Object '_Worksheet' failed"

in line

`LastRow = wSheet.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row)`.

Could anyone help me out? Thanks!

```
Option Explicit

Sub ProtectAll()

Dim wSheet          As Worksheet
Dim Pwd             As String
Dim LastRow         As Integer

Pwd = InputBox("Enter your password to protect all worksheets", "Password Input")
For Each wSheet In Worksheets
LastRow = wSheet.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    wSheet.Range(Cells(12, 1), Cells(LastRow, 18)).Select
    wSheet.Protect Password:=Pwd, AllowFiltering:=True
Next wSheet

End Sub
```

Comment: This isnt how you protect cells. Please see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16684297/hiding-formulas-in-formula-bar/16686868#16686868)

Comment: remove the `After:=[A1],` part or qualify the [A1] with wsheet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code will fail if the sheet is blank as it currently assumes that it finds at least one non blank cell when it sets `LastRow`.

Try using a range object instead, test that it is `Not Nothing` before using `LastRow`.

*Updated: for completeness added a check to see if sheets were already protected, and if so skips and otes these*

```
Option Explicit

Sub ProtectAll()

Dim wSheet          As Worksheet
Dim Pwd             As String
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim strProt As String

Pwd = InputBox("Enter your password to protect all worksheets", "Password Input")
For Each wSheet In Worksheets
Set rng1 = wSheet.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=wSheet.[A1], SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
With wSheet
If .ProtectContents Then
strProt = strProt & .Name & vbNewLine
Else
    .Range(.Cells(12, 1), .Cells(rng1.Row, 18)).Locked = True
    .Protect Password:=Pwd, AllowFiltering:=True
End If
End With
End If
Next wSheet

If Len(strProt) > 0 Then MsgBox strProt, , "These sheet were already protected so were skipped"

End Sub
```

Comment: Still doesn't work (even after removing uncommenting `wSheet.Range(Cells(12, 1), Cells(rng1.Row, 18)).Select`)

Comment: Same line and same error (1004). When I run your code it locks sheet, but not cells.

Comment: @mehow thats certainly true on locking the cells. But it doesn't explain the run-time error.

Comment: + 1 nicely done. If you are using `.FIND` then it is better if you add the error handling. I have already discussed it [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba)