# Does .Value = .Value act similar to Evaluate() function in VBA?

Tags: excel, function, vba, comparison, evaluate

Consider the following snippet. It writes the same formula to two cells `A1` and `A2`

```
Sub Main()
    With Range("A1")
        .Formula = "=1+1"
    End With

    With Range("A2")
        .Formula = "=1+1"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```

The second `with` block uses `.Value = .Value` which calculates/executes the formula therefore the formula disappears from the formula bar. Refer to [hiding formulas from formula bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16684297/hiding-formulas-in-formula-bar/16686868#16686868) for a supportive reference.

[image: .Value = .Value hides the formula from bar]

Now, add another with block

```
With Range("A3")
     .Formula = "=1+1"
End With
Range("A4") = Evaluate(Range("A3").Formula)
```

You add a formula to the cell `A3` then that new cell's formula is being `Evaluated()` into another cell `A4`. The results as shown

[image: Evaluate cells formula]

I think the above kind of shows that `.Value = .Value` and `Evaluate()` do the same thing.

However, The below code pulls value out of a closed workbook using the two mentioned approaches. I have created a workbook `book9.xlsm` for this example with a `hello` put in cell A1. `book9.xlsm` is the one I will be pulling the `A1`'s value from. Consider the code

```
Sub PullValue()
    With Range("A1")
        .Formula = "='C:\Users\admin\Desktop\[book9.xlsm]Sheet1'!A1"
    End With

    With Range("A2")
        .Formula = "='C:\Users\admin\Desktop\[book9.xlsm]Sheet1'!A1"
        .Value = .Value
    End With

    Range("A3").Formula = "='C:\Users\admin\Desktop\[book9.xlsm]Sheet1'!A1"
    Range("A4") = Evaluate(Range("A3").Formula)
End Sub
```

The first `with` block puts a formula in cell's `A1` value from a `book9.xlsm`. It gets executed therefore the pulled value is `hello` but the formula bar shows the actual `.Formula` which is `C:\...`.

The second `with` block uses the `.Value = .Value` as demonstrated above for the evaluation of the formula and hiding the formula by replacing it with the result.

Range("A3") is the same as the first `with` block.

And now (`A4`) I am following the same principle as the first example(first snippet in this question) to `Evaluate()` the formula however It does not work this time.

Please see all activated cells values and formula bar for each one

[image: results]

So now, I cannot say that `.Value = .Value` is equal to `Evaluate()`.

The remarks of [Evalutate()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193019.aspx) say that it can be used with formulas. But in the example I have shown it doesn't work.

[image: Evaluate() msdn]

Are the formulas used as parameters in `Evaluate()` restricted? I've always thought that Evaluate is very powerful but it kind of turns out that `.Value = .Value` actually is even more powerful. Even though they are very similar they are somehow different ( but I am considering it might be my fault as the formula I chose for this example may be restricted or limited ). I think I have shown what makes them two similar and different at the same time. It still is like 50%/50% and I cannot tell exactly if they are the same or not. It would be great if somebody was able to explain what's missing here.

Comment: @lori_m I've rolled back your edit. Please don't radically change the meaning of posts, especially if you're just "guessing" what the question is. See [this meta discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189816/demolition-of-my-question-or-just-a-poor-question-from-me) for more details.

Comment: Evaluate() fails when the referenced cell is in a closed workbook I am afraid. If you will open the referenced book then it will work fine again. It is the way Evaluate function works, it can't read from closed book.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

.value and Evaluate are not the same.
Excel maintains both a value and a formula string for each used cell, and you can get both of these independently using Range.Value and Range.Formula.
 When you use Application.Evaluate to evaluate a string the string is evaluated as a formula on the active worksheet (so actually its better to use Worksheet.Evaluate rather than Application.Evaluate, and its faster too).
 Using Rng1.Value=Rng2.Value copies the value from Rng2 into Rng1 and overwrites the formula of Rng1.
 Using Rng1.Value=Evaluate(rng2.Formula) asks Excel to retrieve the formula string from rng2, evaluate it and return the result to Rng1.
The Evaluate method does not work exactly the same way as a formula in a cell: it has many "quirks" that you need to be aware of (including the fact that it does not work with formulas referring to external closed workbooks): see [my blog post for details](http://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/11/02/evaluate-functions-and-formulas-fun-how-to-make-excels-evaluate-method-twice-as-fast/)
 Also its generally better to use .Value2 rather than .Value: see [Value vs Value2 for details](http://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/11/30/text-vs-value-vs-value2-slow-text-and-how-to-avoid-it/)

Comment: +1 - I had no idea .Value2 was faster than .Value. Thanks for the good answer as well as the blog post.

Answer (score 2):

`.Value = .Value` (within a cell's `With` block) simply sets the value of the cell to its current value, overwriting and removing its formula if it has one.  The `.Value` property simply represents the current value of a cell.  If the cell contains a formula that has not yet been calculated, e.g. if calculation has been turned off, it may not return the formula result, instead returning the previous value of the cell.

`Excel.Application.Evaluate` takes a string value, evaluating the string's contents as if it were a formula or the name of a cell, and returning the value of that cell or formula.  If you pass it a string that can't be mapped to an Excel cell name or isn't a valid formula, you'll get an error.  The purpose of `Evaluate` is to allow dynamically created formulas to be evaluated without having to write the formula out to a cell.  If passed a formula, it should also return a result even if workbook calculation is turned off, though if passed a name, I would expect it to return the current value of a cell, and if workbook calculation is off, that value may not reflect the expected value of the referenced cell.

Presumably since the `.Value` of a cell and `Evaluate()` can return different results, the worksheet formula evaluation engine and the `Application.Evaluate()` engine are different, or at least have some different elements.

Answer (score 1):

`.Value = .Value` and `Evaluate()` are different.

I think you have some confusion with objects and their default properties.

Always keep in mind these two concepts:

1. VBA allows you to use properties and methods without specifying the object. VBA will use their default object. For example when you use `Evaluate()` you actually use `Sheet1.Evaluate()`.
2. VBA allows you to use objects without specifying the property. VBA will use their default property. For example when you use `Range("A1") = 1` you actually use `Range("A1").Formula = 1`. (You actually use `Sheet1.Range("A1").Formula = 1`!)

Going back to your example, when you do `.Value = .Value` you actually do `Range("A2").Value = Range("A2").Value`. The Value property of a cell can be a number, a string, an error, etc. And when it is a number, it could be the *wrong* number, that is not the correct result of the formula in that cell (for example because you have automatic calculation disabled). So `.Value = .Value` is equivalent to `.Formula = "<xxx>"`, where `<xxx>` is the last value calculated on the cell.

When you do `Range("A4") = Evaluate(Range("A3").Formula)` you ask Excel to evaluate the formula and assign the result to the `Formula` property of the range A4 (because the formula property is the default property of a range object.)

Comment: so according to your last sentence Range("A4") should actually say `hello` and not throw an error. Is the error thrown because Evaluate cannot pull a value from a closed workbook then?

Comment: Yes. Excel is fairly good at peeking in closed workbooks when formulas refer to them, even when they are closed. The Evaluate method works with data across workbooks, but only if they are already open. If you know your next Evaluate will try to access data on another workbook, your macro should check if the workbook is closed and open it. But the performances would be much slower (even with `ScreenUpdating = False`) than the formula, because your macro would open the whole workbook, while a formula is able to access only the required data inside a closed file.

Comment: do you have any reference supporting `(You actually use Sheet1.Range("A1").Formula = 1!)` from your answer ? How did you figure out that Formula is the default for Range?

Comment: @mehow I don't have any reference. I think that's what happens because `Range("A2") = "=A1"` works, and because of other similar behaviors, but I could be wrong.

Comment: thanks. Please [**see this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21386768/why-am-i-having-issues-assigning-a-range-to-an-array-of-variants/21406547) in your spare time, it may be interesting to you

Answer (score 0):

Evaluate is a function
And something which use followed by a dot (.) after a function,that is called as property. So ".Value",".Formula",".Text" are  properties of Range which you are using here.

Don't mix up these 2 things.

A function takes input, perform actions using its input variables and return results. And it works on the data type for which it is configured.

.value is a generic property which is not dependent on data type. It can be string, numeric, float or whatever.

so there is possibility where you get error from 1 and other work absolutely fine.