# Why am I having issues assigning a Range to an Array of Variants

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I am having a few problems with some VERY simple lines of code. Let me detail the facts and see if anyone else can replicate this behavior. If any one can replicate I would like to get an explanation of why it is happening.

So lets me start with a very simple line of code THAT WORKS:

```
Dim arr() As Variant
arr = Range("A1:A10")
```

this does as expected, `arr` is assigned the Values of `A1:A10`

now why won't the following line of code work?

```
Dim arr() As Variant
arr = WorkSheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10")
```

I get a Run-Time Error '13' Type mismatch, even though the same range was successfully assigned to the array, just without the Worksheet value.

But

```
Dim arr As Variant
arr = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10")
```

And

```
Dim arr() As Variant
arr = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10")))
```

DOES WORK

Now before you answer please let me give you some more facts.

```
Dim arr() As Variant
arr = Worksheets(1).Range("A1:A10")
```

Does Not Work

and using `Sheets` in place of `Worksheets` also all give the same error.

I have made sure it is the same sheet as the active referenced sheet by using `Range("A1:A10").Worksheet.Name` Following the working code and it indeed says `Sheet1` in the output.

No other workbooks are open so it can't be referencing another workbook either.

Now this last bit of code only adds to my confusion as it totally works!

```
Dim arr() As Variant
Dim SampleRange As Range

Set SampleRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10")
arr = SampleRange
```

So using the SAME RANGE defined the same way on the same sheet now works when I assign it to a Range Variable. and use that! And as expected this works with both the `WorkSheets` and `Sheets` function regardless of how I define the sheet (I can use the index or the Name of the worksheet and all work fine)

If it helps anyone, I am testing this with Excel 2007 on a Windows XP machine. I have not yet tested it on any other machines but I plan to test on 2003 and 2010 on Windows 7 and 8, just haven't had the chance yet.

***UPDATE:*** Not 100% sure if this is the same exact issue as with the array but from a shallow view it seems to be:

```
 Range("B1:B3") = Range("A1:A3")
```

The above code will not work, even if A1:A3 is populated, dates, numeric values, strings, formula anything, it will write blanks into B1:B3

But

```
Range("B1:B3").Value = Range("A1:A3").Value
```

And

```
Range("B1") = Range("A1")
```

*does* work!

Also working is:

```
Range("B1:B3") = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Range("A1:A3")))
```

Comment: `arr = Worksheets(1).Range("A1:A10").Value` works

Comment: @simoco It does not for me, I did also test that along with `Value2`, nothing works all was tested, just forgot I tested that, I still get the same error. Type Mismatch, what OS and versino of excel are you using?

Comment: Excel 2003 / Excel 2013, win 8.1.

Comment: I'm thinking this has something to do with the default behavior of referring to `Range`. Often `Range(X)` can be used to refer to the contents of the range `X`. If we instantiate it as the Range property of a Worksheet, I'm thinking we refer to that hardcoded "Range-ness" of it. However, this does not explain why setting it to a variable bypasses it. Hopefully, someone can come along and explain it. `Value` solves it for me either way, though. Win7, XL2010.

Comment: @simoco That is interesting, when you simply used `arr = Worksheets(1).Range("A1:A10")` did it work? as the `Value` property is typically the default property used in VBA when a property is not specified? And even if not why would the variable take a different property then the array?

Comment: And just to be clear... I experience your original issues the same EXCEPT when I add `.Value` at the end. If I do, no errors in any of the tests above.

Comment: I have no idea why the second method doesn't work when the first does. This is not typically how you'd assign a range directly to an array though: usually you'd declare `arr` as `Variant`, and not as an array of variants, which is what you have here. Using just a regular Variant you will not see this behavior. Adding `.Value` to the end of your second method also fixes the problem, so must be something related to relying on the default property being different between the two approaches.

Comment: @user2140261, `arr = Worksheets(1).Range("A1:A10")` doesn't work.  `arr = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A10")` doesn't work as well. But ``arr = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A10").Value` works without any problems..I'm confused, because `.Value` should be the default property of `Range` object

Comment: @user2140261, changing `Dim arr() As Variant` to `Dim arr As Variant` fixes problem for me and `arr = Worksheets(1).Range("A1:A10")` works fine!

Comment: @TimWilliams I've assigned MANY MANY arrays in the past, just never noticed this bug as I typically always Dim and Assign all my variable at the begining of all code just for the ease of updating in the future, but just something I was playing with and noticed, I think I originally learned to dim the arrays a yer or two ago based on an article from Chip Pearson. I'll try and link the article if I can find it again though.

Comment: @simoco is correct. Removing `()` and just leaving `Dim arr As Variant` will correct the issue on the `Worksheets...` part. Now, how to understand all of this. :D

Comment: @simoco Yeah dimming it in that manner also fixes it for me, for the record the article I was speaking of was [Here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx)

Comment: ANOTHER STRANGE THING: `Dim arr() As Variant:  arr = Sheet1.Range("A1:A10")` work well. Note that I've used `arr()` with brackets

Comment: @simoco Might be something completly unrelated but when using you EXACT code it worked fine but when using a sheet with a different name, in my testin I used *Sample* (first renamed the sheet then ran your code and changed only Sheet1 to Sample, and got a compile error.

Comment: @user2140261 - I see that page: I guess I've never used that notation, but you are correct that's how Chip does it...

Comment: @user2140261 ..look at this [picture](http://www.globaliconnect.com/excel/images/ExcelVBA/VBE/vbe_4.gif). Your sheet has two names: for VBA variable and for tab name (in brackets). I.e. if your sheets has name "VBE_intro" (as in picture) you should use `Sheet1.Range("a1")` in VBA code. Is it true for you? I mean that you should use `Sheeti` corresponding to name "Sample" in brackets for using it as VBA variable

Comment: Probably related to the binding of the Worksheet reference as late binding (`Dim arr() As Variant: Dim sheet As Worksheet: Set sheet = Worksheets("Sheet1"): arr = sheet.Range("A1:A10")`) works fine. Using VarPtr to read the return address of `Range("A1:A10")` (and late binding) they return object references whereas `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10")` returns an object within a variant (offset 1==9) which is probably preventing the Range->Variant() conversion.

Comment: @AlexK. Working off what you said I think that is because `Range` is not a member of the `Worksheets` class, but instead the `Worksheet` class, So in order to get the `Range` variable from the worksheets class, excel already has to convert the Entered parameters into the `Worksheets `class to convert that object into the `Worksheet` object it needs to get the `Range` memeber of that object. But I don't understand is that If I use the `VarType` or `TypeName` function on both representations they all return the same `Range` type, so along with what you are saying it seems

Comment: that both methods return `Range` type variables, where one further returns the `Value` property while the other does not, the same reasoning explains why when explicitly stating the `Value` Property worked for pretty much everyone.  I suppose I am just not at a level of programming where I can understand the WHY of this, and that is exactly why I asked the question. I am looking for a deeper level of knowledge here. @simoco tag you also as you seemed interested as I.

Comment: @AlexK. That's all Ok, but I don't understand why this works `Dim arr As Variant: arr = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10")` but this doesen't `Dim arr() As Variant: arr = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10")`? Note at the brackets after `arr()`

Comment: @simoco Dang Nab-bit, that contradicts everything I ***Thought*** I just *Figured Out*. Because clearly it *IS* returning the Value property of the Range Class in both situations.

Comment: @user2140261, ok, why this doesn't work `Dim arr() As Variant: arr = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10")`, but this works `Dim arr() As Variant: arr = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10").Value` (for me and for BK201)? It's make me confused, because `.Value` is default property..

Comment: @simoco That ***I THINK*** is explained in my double comment, that without explicitly stating the you want the `Value` Property of the `Range` class, that after excel does all the work of converting `Worksheets("Sheet1")` to the `Worksheet` function (note the lack of `S`, because according to the Toolbox in VBA `Range`  ***IS NOT*** a member of `WorkSheets`) that you are then asking for the `Range` Property of the `Worksheet` class and that is EXACTLY what it is returning, not a Property of the `Range` class but the `Range` Object itself. But then that thought process gets thrown out

Comment: When you take into account this works `Dim arr As Variant: arr = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10")`

Comment: @user2140261 i think Tim already pointed it out. there's a difference between `arr As Variant` and `arr() as Variant`. `arr As Variant` may contain objects. `arr() As Variant` cannot and therefore may not be assigned with Objects. following that logic, excel cannot assume the default property `Value` during assigning `arr = Worsheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10")` it already fails.

Comment: @L42 Thats 100% false and is proven to be false by the fact that `Dim arr() As Variant : arr = Range("A1:A10")` works without issues, `arr() as Variant` ***IS*** assigned with objects, and excel DOES assume the default property `Value` during assigning...

Comment: @user2140261 i posted an answer to help you get to see my point. sorry it's long to fit in comment so i posted it as answer.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

No it is not a bug.

> The point is that Value is the default property of the Range Object, so why isn't it implicitly used? Did you have a look at the question I linked? (FROM [CHAT](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46174/discussion-between-user2140261-and-simoco))

The experts posting previous answers have already explained very well in details. I will keep the explanation to minimal and hence let me know if you still have any questions.

Let's understand our objects first. I created this small table which clearly shows what are we handling so that there is no confusion.

[image]

You could also add a `Watch` to see the `Type` for a particular object as shown in the pic below.

[image]

So when you say

```
arr = Range("A1:A10")
```

Excel knows that the default property is `.Value`. However in other case, it doesn't know because Excel is not a mind reader or let's say intelligent enough to understand whether you want to use `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10")` as a `Range` or a `Variant`

Once you explicitly specify your object as a `Range` then Excel knows what you want. For example this works.

```
Dim arr() As Variant
Dim Rng As Range  
Set Rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10")
arr = Rng
```

Comment: +1 for the Watch to show the Type, I had been using TypeName and VarType, and both returned `Range` for every item.

Comment: Hope that clarifies when `.Value` is the default property and when it is not :)

Comment: plus one for `because Excel is not a mind reader or let's say intelligent enough`. this is the most important fact.

Comment: Why would Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10") be treated as a variant, but not Range("A1:A10")?

Answer (score 4):

Let me clarify my comment.
It can't fit to comment to i post it as answer just to at least clear my point.

```
Dim arr As Variant '~~> you declare arr as Variant as what Tim said
```

what does it mean?
It means that `arr` can take on any form (eg. integer, string, array, object and all the other `Variable Type`)

```
Dim arr() as Variant '~~> you declare arr() as array which may contain Varying `Data Type`
```

what does it mean?
It means that `arr()` array variable can store different `Data` types.
That excludes `Objects` or `Collection of Objects`.

Now, why the following works:

```
1. Dim arr() As Variant: arr = Range("A1:A10")
2. Dim arr() As Variant: arr = Sheet1.Range("A1:A10")
3. Dim arr() As Variant: arr = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10").Value
```

This also works:

```
4. Dim arr() as Variant
   Dim rng as Range

   Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10")
   arr = rng
```

Above works because you are not trying to assign `Collections of Objects` into an array.
Instead, you are assigning a specific entity or value.
`Range` is an object but not a `Collection of Objects`.
No.1 example is direct without accessing `Sheets Collection Object`.
Same is true with 
 No.2 since you work with `Sheet1` which is a `Sheet` Object but not `Collection of Sheet Objects`.
No.3 is self explanatory, you assign `.Value` to an `arr` array.
No.4 works because `rng` is already a `Range` object by `Set` which again is not a `Collection of Objects`.

So this:

```
Dim arr() As Variant

arr = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10")
```

doesn't work because Excel will read this as trying to assign `Object` from `Sheets Collection of Objects` and thus error occurs.
I hope this makes sense a bit.

Comment: Both `Range("A1:A3")` and `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A3")` are `Range Objects` regardless of what you say this is a fact. You can type cast them in many ways and every way that you test both versions they will return a `Range` type. And because of that ***BOTH*** should either implicitly work or fail. Also, you are wrong by stating that `Sheets("Sheet1")` returns a Collection of Sheet Objects. `Sheets` itself *IS* a collection of sheets and when passing the parameter of a sheet name the Sheets Class returns a `Sheet` object not its entire collection. Like Mehow I think its just a bug.

Comment: I think @Siddharth Rout already clear this in his post. Sorry i was sloppy in the way i explain things. :) But i'm glad somehow we cleared our confusion.

Answer (score 2):

I would say **an Array of Something is not the same as a Something, since this Something can be an Array of some other things**. If you define something as an Array, what you assign to it has to be an Array, be it an Array of Number, Text, Range, Chart objects, etc.

When things work that we don't expect, I believe it's the built-in data type conversion that makes things easy for us most of the time. This conversion may have to be a direct object, not properties of an object.

For example, Rows and Cols are of type **Long**, but you can throw the Byte/Double type at it:

`Cells(1,1.5)` gives value of `Cells(1,2)`

You don't have to convert 1.5 to Long; Excel does it all in background for you.

When you define an array of something and assign things to it, Excel does type matching behind the scene and set values when possible.

Check with these in the Immediate window:

`?typename(Range("A1:A10").Value)` gives you `Variant()` <-- this is why it works on `Dim arr() As Variant` without any issues

`?typename(Range("A1:A10"))` gives you `Range`. But when you assign it to `arr` where `Dim arr() As Variant`, Excel converts the Range to an Array using the values of that Range.

However, Excel seems to fail converting if it doesn't have direct access to the object, unless you created memory for it. For example:

```
Dim arr() As Variant, oRng As Range
Set oRng = Range("A1:A10")
arr = oRng
Set oRng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10")
arr = oRng
```

The above code is all fine, but it cannot convert and assign `arr = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10")` in one go, unless you throw an array to it (`ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10").Value` is of type **Variant()**).

Comment: Plus one. Again it boils down to @Tim Williams statement that declaring a variable as variant is different from declaring an array variable of variant type.

Comment: THIS IS FALSE! I don't get why you can't understand that. Because `?typename(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10"))` ***ALSO*** gives you Range yet it does ***NOT*** work with `Dim arr() As Variant`, it's kidn of annoying how many people can take information with no actual proof of facts to back up the statement, besides saying it is what it is. Then use a statement thinking it is a factual statement.