# Reading A Worksheet Range To A VBA Array, get script out of range error

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I am tiring alter a macro by seting a range as my array

This works fine

```
Sub FindReplaceByArrays()

Dim FindValues As Variant
Dim ReplaceValues As Variant
Dim i As Long

FindValues = Array("Find1", "Find2", "Find3")
ReplaceValues = Array("Replace1", "Replace2", "Replace3")

Sheets("UnPivot").Select
For i = LBound(FindValues) To UBound(FindValues)
     Columns("P:P").Replace FindValues(i), ReplaceValues(i), xlWhole, xlByColumns, False
Next i

End Sub
```

Tiring to change to the following Sub but get error "Script out of range` and

```
Columns("P:P").Replace FindValues(i), ReplaceValues(i), xlWhole, xlByColumns, False
```

is high lighted

Thanks

```
Sub FindReplaceByArrays2()

Dim FindValues() As Variant
Dim ReplaceValues() As Variant
Dim i As Long

Sheets("UnPivot").Select
FindValues = Range("S2:S30")
ReplaceValues = Range("T2:T30")

For i = LBound(FindValues) To UBound(FindValues)
     Columns("P:P").Replace FindValues(i), ReplaceValues(i), xlWhole, xlByColumns, False
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
Sub FindReplaceByArrays2()

    Dim FindValues As Variant
    Dim ReplaceValues As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    With Sheets("UnPivot")
        FindValues = .Range("S2:S30").Value
        ReplaceValues = .Range("T2:T30").Value

        For i = LBound(FindValues) To UBound(FindValues)
             .Columns("P:P").Replace FindValues(i, 1), ReplaceValues(i, 1), xlWhole, xlByColumns, False
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Note, that I'm using

1. `Dim FindValues As Variant` instead `Dim FindValues() As Variant`
2. `FindValues = .Range("S2:S30").Value` - with `.Value` property (you can read about why you should use it here: [Why am I having issues assigning a Range to an Array of Variants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21386768/why-am-i-having-issues-assigning-a-range-to-an-array-of-variants/))
3. also `FindValues = .Range("S2:S30").Value` actually creates 2D array, that's why I'm using `FindValues(i, 1)`. The same for `ReplaceValues(i, 1)`

and also: [How to avoid using Select/Active statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select):)

Comment: Thanks again simoco, that worked, also thank you for the link it looks helpful.

Comment: The edit was helpful in following what you did, thanks again.