# Pass ListObject to array. type variable String error

Tags: excel, vba, string, variant, listobject

The idea is passing the complete content of a listobject.databodyrange to an array to make operations in memory and not having to access the sheets cells values repeatedly which is very time consuming.

this is the code.

```
 Dim theArray As Variant
     theArray = mylistObject.DataBodyRange.value

MsgBox (theArray(1, 1)) '= column 1 row 1 = first element
```

It works, so far so good.

but!!! since theArray is dimensioned as Variant, their elements are NOT strings, So when passing every of the values of theArray into a function that requires a string an error appears.

what to do?

Note: I know I might change the data type of the function itself to variant, but this function is called from so many routines that i dont dare to touch it. I rather prefer try to look for the way to transform the content of that variant into a string

like `theArray(i,j)`  to `str(thearray(i,j))` (which does not work)

some help, some ideas?

EDIT 1:
this is the line of the error:

```
Dim theclaims As Variant
      theclaims = rawClsTbl.DataBodyRange.value
For i = LBound(theclaims, 1) To UBound(theclaims, 1)
myText = deleteRefSigns(theclaims(i, 2))
etc
```

error: byref argument type missmatch

where:
    Function deleteRefSigns(txT As String) As String

i will be trying the solutions proposed.

thx

Related questions:
I asked in overflow myself this question some time ago:
[Passing Listobject Range to array and getting error "out of range"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54111015/passing-listobject-range-to-array-and-getting-error-out-of-range)
and read also this one 
[Excel VBA Type Mismatch Error passing range to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25234592/excel-vba-type-mismatch-error-passing-range-to-array)
and several others.

Comment: Can you post the function code?

Comment: `Dim MyStr As  String: MyStr = CStr(theArray(1, 1))` should work. Can you please post a [mcve] that reproduces the error? • Note: always declare it as array `Dim theArray() As Variant` to ensure it contains an array. Otherwise it will contain only a value if you do `theArray = Range("A1").value` which might easily fail if your range is dynamic.

Comment: Please, at the very least, ***post the line of code that is failing.***

Comment: You could put all data from your Table directly into theArray as string in one-go (you will need your Tablename referred directly in code)

Comment: @evr that would be great!!! but how.

Comment: EDIT 1 include the exact code of the errors

Comment: A ref error is not a `String` but an `Error` type. What does `deleteRefSigns` do? Either test if the input is a `String` or can be coerced to one, or modify `deleteRefSigns` to validate the input.

Comment: @Berlines Like This: theclaims=[Table1&""]  In this case Table1 is the name of your ListObject.

Comment: @PeH  solution works. cstr is the solution. remains the question if it is possible to create an array out of the values of a range of a listobject being directly strings.

Comment: @Berlines see my answer, so you can mark it as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
Dim MyStr As String
MyStr = CStr(TheArray(1, 1))
```

Note: Always declare it as a forced array not just as `Variant` …

```
Dim TheArray() As Variant 'Variant array (can only be an array)
Dim TheArray As Variant 'Variant (can be a value or array)
```

… to ensure it contains an array. Otherwise it will contain only a value if you do

```
TheArray = Range("A1").Value
```

which might easily fail if your range is dynamic.

---

If you read a range into an array like

```
Dim TheArray() As Variant
TheArray = Range("A1:C20").Value
```

then there is no possibility to declare the array as `String` it is forced to be `Variant` by design.

Comment: Thanks @PeH. oftentimes it as important to know what you CANNOT do in a language as what you can do. It is obvious that microsoft did not "modernized" VBA for ages. As enhancement to your answer other "extra" possibility is dump the variant array with a for loop into a string array. that will avoid the need to use Cstr() everywhere in the code.

Comment: Dim TheArray() As Variant
TheArray = [A1:C20&""]
will give an variant array with all items as a string

Comment: Actually I never had issues with a variant array of values. Actually if you try to push a number into a string variable it automatically casts into a string. There is no need to explicitly convert it with  `CStr()`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you don't want `deleteRefSigns` to modify the argument passed by the calling procedure.  If so, you can pass the argument by value...

```
Function deleteRefSigns(ByVal txT As String) As String
```