# excel VBA populate listobject with array values depends on datatype of array variant/string

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, populate, listobject

I have to manipulate data in Listobjects of Excel and instead of populating columns with loops I am trying to paste the values of an array into a listobject position in one go to speed up things (accessing the list object and cells updating one by one is very slow).

I posted some weeks ago this question in SO:
[Pass ListObject to array. type variable String error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57097268/pass-listobject-to-array-type-variable-string-error)

Nevertheless I am observing the following:

```
'variables
Dim mylistObject As ListObject
    Set mylistObject = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("training").ListObjects(1)
Dim i As Integer

' the two arrays to be pasted are defined differently
Dim theArray() As Variant
    theArray = mylistObject.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.value
    ' where column 1 is populated with numbers.
Dim otherArray() As String
    otherArray = Split("1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9", ",")

'lets paste both arrays with insertion point a particular cell (item 5)

 ' a) if the two ranges are the same size, i.e. one column copied I can do:
mylistObject.ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange.value = theArray

' b) lets paste the two arrays in from item 5 on using resize (note ubound of thearray is 9, i.e. base 1)
mylistObject.ListColumns(3).DataBodyRange.item(5).Resize(UBound(theArray), 1).value = theArray

' c) lets paste the otherarray in column 4 (note ubound of thearray is 8, i.e. base 0)
mylistObject.ListColumns(4).DataBodyRange.item(5).Resize(UBound(otherArray) + 1, 1).value = otherArray

'the classical but slow way to paste value by value is:
For i = LBound(otherArray) To UBound(otherArray)
    mylistObject.ListColumns(5).DataBodyRange.item(4 + i).value = otherArray(i)
Next i
```

I get this result (see picture) which is really strange. Why pasting the second array (otherarray) does not work when the array is of the type string.

if you are wondering why I simply dont change the otherarray to variant is because then I can not generate otherarray using split() method.

[image]

Comment: It's nothing to do with it being a string. If you step through you will see that `otherarray` is 1D and hence needs to be transposed (it is "horizontal" or a row when written to a sheet by default).

Comment: ohhhhhhhhhh my god!!!!! and you transpose it with application.transpose(otherarray). I would mark your answer as "the answer" but I can only vote up, dont have the possibility to mark as answer. thanks mate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an array is a one-dimensional array it is supposed to be horizontal.
Thats why I only got the firts value pasted in all the cells.

for properly paste in a column a one dimensional array it is neccesary to transpose it with

```
mylistObject.ListColumns(4).DataBodyRange.item(5).Resize(UBound(otherArray) + 1, 1).value =application.transpose(other_array)
```

where other_array is a one demensionla with which we want to populate column 4 from item 5 on in vertical.