# "Method or Data Member Not Found" when Dim'ing Worksheet as Worksheet but not Variant

Tags: vba, excel

Consider this simple example. In a new sheet create a ActiveX Checkbox called Checkbox1

Try the following two subroutines. The first does not compile with a "Method or Data Member Not Found" error, the second one works fine.

Why doesn't the first example work?

```
Option Explicit

Sub DoesntWork()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets(1)

MsgBox "Checkbox state is: " + CStr(ws.CheckBox1.Value)

End Sub

Sub Works()
Dim ws As Variant
Set ws = Worksheets(1)

MsgBox "Checkbox state is: " + CStr(ws.CheckBox1.Value)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with the line `ws.CheckBox1.Value`. You can't use it like this and hence you are getting that error. Try this

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim objole As OLEObject

    Set ws = Worksheets(1)

    Set objole = ws.OLEObjects("CheckBox1")

    MsgBox "Checkbox state is: " & objole.Object.Value
End Sub
```

If you want to use the Object directly then you can also use this

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Worksheets(1)

    MsgBox "Checkbox state is: " & Worksheets(ws.Name).CheckBox1.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: That's weird.
 Why wouldn't it I be able to access it through ws.Checkbox1 but it works fine through Worksheets(ws.Name).Checkbox1?

Comment: I can give you the answer but I want you to find it yourself ;). Do this. In your `Sub Works()`, Put a `Watch` on the the object `ws` and then see what is the type of `ws` during runtime.

Comment: You may want to see [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21386768/why-am-i-having-issues-assigning-a-range-to-an-array-of-variants/21411922#21411922) on how to add a `Watch`

Comment: I was following the locals window which did show the difference between the two. So I can see that `Dim ws As Worksheet` gives me a `Worksheet/Sheet1 type`. And `Dim wsObj as Object` gives me a `Object/Sheet1` type. But when I expand both `ws` and `wsObj` in the Locals Window, they both list `CheckBox1` as a property...so it must have something to do with forcing a worksheet into a `Worksheet` type vs. `Object`, but I'm still missing something with Excel's object model...

Comment: `Checkbox1` shows only for Variant/Object/Worksheets/Sheet1(in this case) and not for `Worksheet`. If you use intellisense, you will not get the `.Checkbox1` option when you declare ws as worksheet