# Data type confusion when trying to create VBA arrays from Excel ranges

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, type-conversion, range

I have two sets of data in Excel, and I am trying to compare them in VBA. All the data is numeric (integers).

The "new" data is in a table, which gets copied over the "old" data as a range, and then the "new" data table gets updated.

Data format:

| ID | Parameter_1 | Parameter_2 | Parameter_3 | etc.... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 3 | 7 | 9 | etc.... |
| 67890 | 1 | 2 | 3 | etc.... |
| etc.... | etc.... | etc.... | etc.... | etc.... |

My code:

```
...
Sub sub1()

new_rows = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("new").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
old_rows = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("old").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
Dim new_data() As Variant
Dim old_data() As Variant
new_data = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("new").Range("A1:G" & new_rows).Value
old_data = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("old").Range("A1:G" & old_rows).Value
...
Dim update_tracker() As Variant
ReDim update_tracker(rows, columns)
...
updates_recorded = 0
For row_new = 2 To new_rows
     ID = new_data(row_new, 1)
     [code to match corresponding row in old_data that has same ID]

     new_Parameter_1 = new_data(row_new, 4)
     old_Parameter_1 = old_data(row_old, 4)
     new_Parameter_2 = etc....
     [all other data parameters]

     If new_Parameter_1 <> old_Parameter_1 Then
          update_tracker = track_updates(update_tracker, updates_recorded, ID, old_Parameter_1, new_Parameter_1, 1)
          updates_recorded = updates_recorded + 1
     End If
     [if statements for all other parameters]
Next row_new
[irrelevant code to put data into Excel]
End Sub

Function track_updates(update_tracker, updates_recorded, ID, old_Parameter, new_Parameter, parameter_number)
     If updates_recorded > 0 Then
          ReDim Preserve update_tracker(start To UBound(update_tracker, 1), [same columns])
     End If
     update_tracker(UBound(update_tracker, 1), col_1) = ID
     update_tracker(UBound(update_tracker, 1), col_2) = old_Parameter
     update_tracker(UBound(update_tracker, 1), col_3) = new_Parameter
     update_tracker(UBound(update_tracker, 1), col_4) = parameter_number

     track_updates = update_tracker
End Function
```

An error comes up for the 4th line: "Type mismatch". This is regardless if the arrays are `Integer` or `Double`.

`VarType([range].Value)` returns `8204` for both the new and the old ranges and the data is literally identical, yet the data can only be saved from the table into the first array.

If I `Dim` all the arrays as `Variant` then this part of the code works, but later when the `ID` number is being saved to the `update_tracker` the same error comes up.

Even though all 3 arrays are of type `Variant`, putting `?VarType(ID)` into the "Immediate" window when debugging returns `5`, which indicates that the number is somehow saved as a `Double`.

Using a different approach, from [an answer I found on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21386768/why-am-i-having-issues-assigning-a-range-to-an-array-of-variants):

```
Dim old_data() As Variant
Dim r As Range
Set r = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("old").Range("A1:G" & old_rows)
old_data = r
```

results in the whole `old_data` array just being full of zeros.

Please help!

Comment: Pretty sure your arrays need to be type variant, when you are passing a range of values, no matter the type of data. See the late Chip Pearson's article on [Arrays and Ranges in VBA](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx)

Comment: Could you share the complete code so we could draw a conclusion? BTW, the line should be `old_data = r.Value` (`r` is a range, `r.Value` is an array (if more than one cell in `r`)) and there is a difference when using `Dim old_data As Variant` without the parentheses. But let's first see the code.

Comment: @VBasic2008 I added all the relevant code

Comment: *ID number is being saved to the update_tracker*:  You've never declared nor set `col_1` to a value.  `?VarType(ID)` => the subtype of the stored value, not the type.  Suggest you put `Option Explicit` at the top of your module, and declare all variables.

Answer (score -1):

Since you're assiging a 2-dimensional array use `Dim old_data As Variant` instead of `Dim old_data() As Variant` (remove the braces)

Comment: Why?
Also, this didn't help.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).