# Excel VBA 'Overflow' Error Returning Range to UDF

Tags: excel, vba

I have a UDF which gets a range of data and trims off x number of rows from the top (row headers).

I call this to load the data range into a variant variable as an array.

I use this function in this way on all worksheets and it works fine every time, however on 1 particular worksheet it throws an 'overflow' error and I don't know why.

I call the function like this:

```
Dim vTableArray As Variant
vTableArray = Get_Data_Range(Invoices", "A11", 2)
```

The Function is:

```
Function Get_Data_Range(sWorksheetName As String, sDataRange As String, iResizeOffset As Long) As Range

    Set Get_Data_Range = Sheets(sWorksheetName).Range(sDataRange).CurrentRegion
    Set Get_Data_Range = Get_Data_Range.Offset(iResizeOffset, 0).Resize(Get_Data_Range.Rows.Count - iResizeOffset, Get_Data_Range.Columns.Count)

End Function
```

When I debug the code, the error is thrown on the 'End Function' line of the UDF.

The range of data has 4925 rows and 59 columns. There are no errors in the data range.

Any help fixing this error appreciated.

Comment: Note that your function is not a UDF. A UDF (=User defined function) is a function that you can use in an Excel formula. UDFs have some limitations (eg they might not modify a sheet). In your case, `Get_Data_Range` is a normal function.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I've found the answer to my own question by reading this post:

[Why am I having issues assigning a Range to an Array of Variants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21386768/why-am-i-having-issues-assigning-a-range-to-an-array-of-variants)

If I explicitly tell the variant array to get .value2 from the range, the code works.

```
'   Load Data Into Array
    vTableArray = Get_Data_Range("Invoices", "A11", 2).Value2
```