# VBA - How to get the result of a formula ? (.Value always returns 0)

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, evaluate

I want to get the result of a formula contained in a cell, but I always get 0 returned, instead of the real results.

I have the following:

```
Set c = .Cells (5,5)

MsgBox (c.Formula) ' this return the following: = ASIN (W22-V22/$D$7)*180/PI() 
MsgBox (c.Value) ' this returns 0
MsgBox (c.Value2) ' this returns 0 as well
```

And even if I try with Evaluate:

```
evaluation = Application.Evaluate (c.Formula) 
MsgBox (c.Value) ' it still returns 0
```

Comment: I tested this code and it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

Zero is the correct answer if both **V22** and **W22** are zero.

Comment: No they are not, I have other results shown in my Excel in the whole column: 1.1, 0.6, 0.9, .... but in VBA (.Value) returns 0 for all of them.

Comment: Is Calculation Mode Manual or Automatic??

Comment: Make sure there are no extra spaces that would make the formula invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

```
Sub formVal()

Dim c As Range

Set c = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(5, 5)

MsgBox (c.Formula) 
MsgBox (c.Value)
MsgBox (c.Value2)



End Sub
```

Comment: I see no changes, but I tried it and it did return the same results as before: 0 all the time

Comment: Maybe you've got your row or column ID wrong? It's Cells(rowIndex, columnID). You can also write: c =...Cells("E5")

Comment: And just btw, isn't your formula supposed to be =ASIN((W22-V22)/$D$7)*180/PI() ?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17745656/does-value-value-act-similar-to-evaluate-function-in-vba?rq=1