# Use a value from a cell which is written with formulas

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have two columns in Excel. The first(column C) has cells with values, the second one(column B), I had used a script to extract some values from the first one with Excel formulas.

Now I want to use the values from the second column in another column and the script doesn't have any errors but gives me empty cells because the second column contains formulas.

Is it possible to paste values or to extract only the values from the second column?

Here is my code:

```
for i in range(0,len(listaunica)):
ws4.cell(row=i+1,column=3).value=listaunica[i]


for i in range(0,len(listaunica)):
    ws4.cell(row=i+1,column=2).value='=iferror(find(".",C{0}),C{0})'.format(i+1)
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22613272/how-to-access-the-real-value-of-a-cell-using-the-openpyxl-module-for-python

Answer (score 1):

I do not fully understand your situation, so I will explain some possibilities:

(1) You have an Excel workbook that was *saved using Excel itself*. In this case, column B should have *both* formulas and the results of those formulas, because Excel would have calculated them.

(2) You have an Excel workbook that was saved using some other method, such as being written by OpenPyXL, and has not (yet) been opened *and saved* by Excel. In this case, you most likely have *either* formulas *or* results stored in column B.

When you are reading using OpenPyXL, you have to choose whether you want formulas or results. This is controlled by the `data_only` parameter. Set this to `True` if you want just the results. If your workbook was saved in Excel, and thus has both formulas and results, then the way to read them both in OpenPyXL is to open the workbook twice, once with `data_only=False` and once with `data_only=True`. Cumbersome, but that is how OpenPyXL is designed.

If you have a workbook from scenario (2), and column B still looks like it has formulas, then most likely trying to open the workbook using `data_only=True` will just return zeros for column B. You won't be able to get the results from this workbook until you open it in Excel and then save it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for i in range(0,len(listaunica)):
ws4.cell(row=i+1,column=3).value=listaunica[i]
for i in range(0,len(listaunica)):
ws4.cell(row=i+1,column=2).value='=iferror(find(".",C{0}),C{0})'.format(i+1)
ws4.cell(row=i+1,column=2).value = ws4.cell(row=i+1,column=2).value
```

For reference [Does .Value = .Value act similar to Evaluate() function in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17745656/does-value-value-act-similar-to-evaluate-function-in-vba)?