# Excel 2010 VBA "=IFERROR..."

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using VBA to introduce formulas in my local database regarding some conditions. Here is an example of the code I'm using:

```
Range("CP" & l).Formula = "=IFERROR(((T" & l & "*6)-SUM(U" & l & ":Z" & l & "))/(T" & l & "*6);"""")"
```

Were "l" is my first blank row (it's working)

The formula is working very well, but the problem I have is that the code is returning only the value of the result in my cell, but I would like to see the whole formula in my cell.

Is it something that can be possible to do ?

*** The real problem is that the formula IS NOT in the formula bar. The Code write the score, but not the formula. If I do a test with

```
Range("CP" & l).Formula = "=((T" & l & "*6)-SUM(U" & l & ":Z" & l & "))/(T" & l & "*6)"
```

I see the formula in the formula bar.

I really don't understand...

Thanks :)

Marie

Comment: If you select the cell, do you not see the formula in the formula bar?  Do you simply want to *display* the formula, rather than its evaluated result?

Comment: Before the post was edited there was an extra space before the equal sign: `" =IFERROR(` this would output text and not the actual formula.

Comment: try doing a bit of reverse engineering based on [*`this`*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16684297/hiding-formulas-in-formula-bar/16686868#16686868)

Comment: Hi !

David Zemens wrote "If you select the cell, do you not see the formula in the formula bar?"

I don't see the formula in the formula bar, and it's exactly my problem !

Thanks again for your help :)

Comment: I can't think of any reason how the formula would not appear in the formula bar, unless you have another part of code that is replacing the evaluation with the `.Value`. I see Sid is troubleshooting with you, so I will leave it to him.

Comment: No, the cell doesn't have any protection. I have an error message when using IFERROR ... seems that the Code is taking it as a part of the code, not a string to copy in te cell. I've try too with .Value with the same result ...

Answer (score 3):

> but I would like to see the whole formula in my cell.

To display the formula in the cell instead of the values, you have 3 options

1. Format the cells as text and then use the code which you have.

   `Range("CP" & l).Formula = "=IFERROR(((T" & l & "*6)-SUM(U" & l & ":Z" & l & "))/(T" & l & "*6);"""")"`
2. Change `.Formula` to `.Value` and add a `'` before the `=` sign

   `Range("CP" & l).Value = "'=IFERROR(((T" & l & "*6)-SUM(U" & l & ":Z" & l & "))/(T" & l & "*6);"""")"`
3. Activate the option `File Tab | Options | Advanced | "Show Formulas in cells instead...."`

[image]

Comment: It's works, but I beleive I didn't giva you the right information. I want to see the result, but I want also the formula be in the cell.

Comment: When you enter the formula in the cell, you will see the result. If you want to see the formula then you can check it in the formula bar.

Comment: Not Possible... Can you expand the formula bar horizontally?

Comment: What *is* in the formula bar? Perhaps some other line of code is overwriting the cell with its `.Value`?

Comment: @Marie-AndréeMorin: But you can see the value in the cell? If yes, can you also check if you are on the right sheet? because your range object is not fully qualified. for example `sheets("sheet1").range(...)` Check the same cell in other sheets. Else upload your file in a file sharing site and share the link here. lemme have a look.

Comment: I tried with Sheet5.Cells(l, 94) = " ... Sheets.Range("CO"&l&) = ... No bether results

Comment: @Marie-AndréeMorin: Like I said, May I see the file?

Comment: @Marie-AndréeMorin: Can you upload it to a file sharing site and then share the link here?