# Protected sheet in Excel: Allowing any user to edit a range, but not be able to select anything else

Tags: excel

I want to make it so the only things a user can do is click the dropdowns of my Data Validation fields, press any of the macro buttons, and nothing more. No ability to select arbitrary cells, etc.

I tried doing Protect Sheet with a "Allow users to Edit Range" but then when I make it so users can't "select locked cells" it doesn't let me select the dropdowns either.

Comment: see [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16684297/hiding-formulas-in-formula-bar/16686868#16686868), see if you get an idea

Comment: That is really complicated. There's no way for me to simply say "lock everything except this area of the sheet"?

Comment: the answer you have accepted is pretty much exactly what you need. It's well described in the link ive given you but I guess you didnt feel like reading through.. anyhow Im glad youve got your solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to right click on the cells that contain Data Validation > Format Cells > Protection and uncheck the "Locked" checkbox.